# Publish telerik application

Tags: telerik

I want to publish the telerik app builder.It shows this issue.

Build failed: One or more errors occurred..
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one matching element
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Telerik.BlackDragon.Common.Data.TargetResultDataExtensions.GetRelativeOutputPath(TargetResultData targetResultData, DevicePlatform platform)
   at Telerik.BlackDragon.Common.Data.TargetResultDataExtensions.GetRelativePathToPackage(TargetResultData targetResultData, DevicePlatform platform)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at Telerik.BlackDragon.Client.Build.Services.BuildService.d__2.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at Telerik.BlackDragon.Client.Build.CloudBuild.ExecuteCore(IHttpServiceContext httpServiceContext, LogHelper logger)
   at Telerik.BlackDragon.Client.Build.CloudTaskBase.ExecuteCore()
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one matching element
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Telerik.BlackDragon.Common.Data.TargetResultDataExtensions.GetRelativeOutputPath(TargetResultData targetResultData, DevicePlatform platform)
   at Telerik.BlackDragon.Common.Data.TargetResultDataExtensions.GetRelativePathToPackage(TargetResultData targetResultData, DevicePlatform platform)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at Telerik.BlackDragon.Client.Build.Services.BuildService.d__2.MoveNext()

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have this error

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one matching element
```

It means that your linq query returns more than one element. if it's normal, you should use `FirstOrDefault()`.

`SingleOrDefault()` throws an exception if more than one element exists.